# how to deploy qt based application with oracle plugin

Tags: oracle, qt, deployment

just wrote application based QT with OCI plugin but i can't deploy it.
i did the following steps:

1. installed QT 4.7 SDK
2. Installed the OCI plugin:

   set INCLUDE=%INCLUDE%;c:\oracle\oci\include

   set LIB=%LIB%;c:\oracle\oci\lib\msvc

   cd %QTDIR%\src\plugins\sqldrivers\oci

   qmake -o Makefile oci.pro

   nmake
3. i followed: "Building static Qt on Windows with MSVC"
   edited the \mkspecs\win32-X\qmake.conf:

   QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE                      = -O2 -MT

   CONFIG += qt warn_on release incremental flat link_prl precompile_header autogen_precompile_source copy_dir_files debug_and_release debug_and_release_target
4. then on the Qt dir:

   configure -static -release

   nmake sub-src
5. i'm not sure about the next steps but in my application dir i ran:

   qmake -o Makefile myProgram.pro

   nmake

i get .exe file in release but i get error that the OCI driver is not loaded...
please assist me ,
i had no errors in any step i made

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you first compile your static version of Qt and then compile the OCI plugin? You could also do this in one step by setting the appropriate configure switch -qt-sql-oci and adding the required include and lib dirs.

Because, in your scenario, which qmake did you use to compile your OCI plugin? The static one you intend to use for your app isn't build yet. So it seems your OCI plugin was build with one Qt version, whereas your application uses another (static) Qt version. This mismatch is most probably the cause of your problem.

Also, when using static plugins, you have to use the `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN` macro. See here for more details http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/plugins-howto.html#static-plugins

As requested, here a step by step instruction how it should work:

1. Extract the qt sources for your static Qt version, lets say in C:\Qt\4.7.0-static
2. Change qmake.conf the way you already did.
3. In your visual studio command line, change directory to C:\Qt\4.7.0-static and do this:

   configure -static -release -qt-sql-oci -I C:\oracle\oci\include -L c:\oracle\oci\lib\msvc
4. Do a nmake sub-src
5. Then, change the qt version you use for your app to the one just compiled and execute "Run qmake" and "Rebuild project" from the build menu in QtCreator (as you installed Qt SDK, I'm assuming you're using it)
6. It hopefully works now - using the -qt-sql-oci switch causes a static build of the oci driver.

Comment: can u plz describe me the steps i should make ? 
sorry i just encounter too many problem with that... diging pieces of infos :(

Comment: when i try to run from the visual studio command prompt the following command: configure -static -release -qt-sql-oci -I C:\oracle\oci\include -L c:\oracle\oci\lib\msvc

i get the following error: 
'configure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Ensure that you changed to the correct dir, eg. C:\Qt\4.7.0-static\ depending on your setup, like you did in your description in step 4.

Comment: in C:\Qt\4.7.0-static\ i have only my project source files
i have configure.exe in C:\Qt\2010.05\qt

Comment: You need to download a separate version of the Qt lib and build it using the parameters specified above. The version in C:\Qt\2010.05\qt is a MinGW precompiled non-static version. If you re-compiled it there as a static version without doing a confclean you most probably screwed it up. So the best thing to do is re-install the sdk, get a separate version of the Qt lib and compile it as static with the -qt-sql-oci option.

Comment: i downloaded and installed qt-win-opensource-4.7.0-vs2008.exe with Visual studio installed.
when running C:\Qt\4.7.0-static\configure command i still get same error i described.
the configure is located in C:\Qt\4.7.0.
but if i run it from there it goes over all examples etc' and not my app i assume...
what should i do in order to run the configure on my app ?

Comment: You can't and don't need to run configure on your app. Also, you don't to need to download the visual studio version of qt, as this is a precompiled dynamically linked version. You need to compile your custom static version using http://get.qt.nokia.com/qt/source/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.7.0.zip - after that, rebuild your app using this qt version. Also, keep your directory structur clean ,for example c:\qt\4.7.0-static for your static qt, c:\qt\2010.05\ for your QtCreator installation and c:\qt\workspace for your app, for example.

Comment: If you're using visual studio 2008, your configure line should look exactly like this: configure -platform win32-msvc2008 -static -release -qt-sql-oci -I C:\oracle\oci\include -L c:\oracle\oci\lib\msvc

Comment: nmake result with an error 
C:\Qt\4.7.0-static\src\3rdparty\zlib\inffast.c : fatal error C1083: Cannot open compiler intermediate file: 'C:\DOCUME~1
\eyalk\LOCALS~1\Temp\_CL_31e7d4fcin': Permission denied
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x1'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

any idea ?